# How to get or read data from nested list and display as list in the Flutter widget?

Tags: list, flutter

I have list of questions here and I can retrieve them easily but how do I get the options from the nested list? I want to display as list, here my code

When try to get the options list it gives me something that doesn't look list at all.

```
class QuizData {
  
  List<BrainData> getData = [
    BrainData(
      questionID: "biology1",
      question:
          "Pine, fir, spruce, cedar, larch and cypress are the famous timber-yielding plants of which several also occur widely in the hilly regions of India. All these belong to",
      
      options: [
        "angiosperms",
        "gymnosperms",
        "monocotyledons",
        "dicotyledons",
      ],
       answer: [false, true, false, false],
    ),
  ];
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My questions was how do I access the options list and display in Flutter widget?